# htaccess rule to remove .php confilicting with another rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I had a rule the removed the necessity of having .php after my admin page, 'admin.php':

```
# Don't require .php extension to load php page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

The rule worked fine untill I needed to add the below rules;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?action=viewCategoryName&categoryName=$1&page_identifier=$2 [L,QSA,B]
```

and, the one effecting the first rule;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?action=viewHomepageName&page_identifier=$1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Im wondering if how I've made the CMS and its query strings is lending to this being impossible to rectify. Could do a redirect from admin.php to admin/ but if possible I would like the usability of the first rule carried forward.

Cheers!
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organize your rules like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?action=viewCategoryName&categoryName=$1&page_identifier=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?action=viewHomepageName&page_identifier=$1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Comment: works perfectly! Would you mind explaing why this works as such? Is it similar to how css cascades?

Comment: These rules are applied from top to bottom. So most specific rule should be placed at top and most generic like `^([^/]+)/?$` needs to come at last.

Comment: thank you so much, doing some reading the [L] seems to stop the rule. Could you explain the [OR] at the end of the first line? Thanks again anubhava! :)

Comment: `OR` simply means alternation so it means if request is for a file OR a directory then don't use any rules below. [You can read more](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)